# How to deserialize a JSON array containing different data types to a single object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Over the last few days I have been researching on how to deserialize a JSON response to and C# object. The JSON is valid but I can not get any JSON to C# converters to convert it. I also cannot find an answer on Stackoverflow that works for this instance.
The JSON Response is:

```
[
  {
    "SEX": "Male",
    "BREED": "Opifex",
    "PVPRATING": 1301,
    "NAME": "Kilmanagh",
    "FIRSTNAME": "Big",
    "PVPTITLE": "Freshman",
    "LASTNAME": "Kahuna",
    "CHAR_DIMENSION": 5,
    "ALIENLEVEL": 30,
    "RANK_name": "Vindicator",
    "HEADID": 40281,
    "PROFNAME": "Guru",
    "LEVELX": 220,
    "PROF": "Martial Artist",
    "CHAR_INSTANCE": 12734,
    "SIDE": "Omni"
  },
  {
    "ORG_DIMENSION": 5,
    "RANK_TITLE": "President",
    "ORG_INSTANCE": 9911,
    "NAME": "Elements of Destruction",
    "RANK": 0
  },
  "2016/04/06 08:37:26"
]
```

From my inspection it is an array that contains two objects and a string.
I have used the following to attempt to convert it to an object:

```
 resultArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonWhoisResult>>(data);
 and
 result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWhoisResult>(data);
```

Either way I get an error:

> Error converting value  ...(snip)... [ConsoleApplication6.JsonWhoisResult]'. Path '', line 1, position 536.`

I do not know if I have the object wrong, or if I am using incorrect code for this JSON format. I am using:

```
public class JsonWhoisResult
{
    public stats stats { get; set; }
    public header header { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
}

public class header
{
    public int ORG_DIMENSION { get; set; }
    public string RANK_TITLE { get; set; }
    public int ORG_INSTANCE { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int RANK { get; set; }
}

public class stats
{
    public string SEX { get; set; }
    public string BREED { get; set; }
    public int PVPRATING { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
    public string PVPTITLE { get; set; }
    public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
    public int CHAR_DIMENSION { get; set; }
    public int ALIENLEVEL { get; set; }
    public string RANK_name { get; set; }
    public int HEADID { get; set; }
    public string PROFNAME { get; set; }
    public int LEVELX { get; set; }
    public string PROF { get; set; }
    public int CHAR_INSTANCE { get; set; }
    public string SIDE { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone has any solutions I would really appreciate it. I have several more that use this type of style. If I can get a solution then I should be able to apply it to the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your JSON is an array you cannot deserialize into a single `JsonWhoisResult`, and because your array contains disparate object types, you cannot deserialize directly into a `List<JsonWhoisResult>`.  You will need to make a custom `JsonConverter` to handle this situation.  The converter can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to deserialize the JSON, then manually extract each item into its appropriate object type and populate a single `JsonWhoisResult` as you want.  Something like this should work:

```
class JsonWhoisResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(JsonWhoisResult));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        JsonWhoisResult result = new JsonWhoisResult();
        result.stats = array[0].ToObject<stats>();
        result.header = array[1].ToObject<header>();
        result.datetime = array[2].ToString();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
JsonWhoisResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWhoisResult>(json, new JsonWhoisResultConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d1hkCn

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The result is: Additional information: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: String. Path '', line 1, position 536.This JSON is a bit unorthodox and driving me up the wall.

Comment: Things to check: (1) Is your JSON exactly as posted in the question, or is it wrapped in another object?  If the latter, the converter will need to be modified to compensate. (2) Are you calling DeserializeObject exactly as shown in my answer?  I've added a fiddle to show that this converter should work.  Check that against your code.

Comment: Brain, the JSON comes from: http://people.anarchy-online.com/character/bio/d/5/name/Kilmanagh/bio.xml?data_type=json. I pasted the exact JSON. Your dotnetfiddle works like a charm. I am using webclient to download the JSON, then using JsonConvert.ToString. Maybe that is making the difference.

Comment: I changed it to download.string, and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot, you definitely know what you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.net's support for `dynamic` to do this. I just tested this *with the JSON as you pasted it above*, and it works - but note, this is not strongly typed.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

// value is "Freshman"
Console.WriteLine("result[0].PVPTITLE = '{0}'", result[0].PVPTITLE);

// value is "President"
Console.WriteLine("result[1].RANK_TITLE = '{0}'", result[1].RANK_TITLE);

// value is 2016-04-06 08:37:27
Console.WriteLine("result[2] '{0}'", (DateTime)result[2]);
```