# Json to C# object handling dynamic properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to implement the json structure in c# objects and I am trying to understand how I can use the correct object depending on the type. For example:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }

}
public class Content
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Item> child { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> model { get; set;}
    public string[] color {get; set;}
}
```

Please note this is just an example there are more properties for each object. If Json contains type = "Boy" how can I generate the boy object.

Example JSON:

```
string json = @"
            {
            'name': 'Object 1',
            'content': {
                'body': {
                    'id': 'body',
                    'type': 'Body'
                },
                'style': {
                    'id': 'style',
                    'type': 'Style'
                },
                'DynamicName-123': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-123',
                    'type': 'Row'
                    'model': {},
                    'colors': []
                },
                'DynamicName-434': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-434',
                    'type': 'Column'
                    'model': {},
                    'colors': []
                },
                'DynamicName-223': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-223',
                    'type': 'Item'
                    'model': {},
                    'colors': []
                }
            }
        }";
```

Comment: Can you change the generated json to include the type, or is it data you are receiving? In case you can't change it, I think you might have to implement  your own custom JsonConverter and overwrite the read method based on properties

Comment: Yes the json includes type in the json and also Id which is static. @Icepickle

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. Also, create a [mcve] including some example JSON. See for example [How to deserialize a JSON array containing different data types to a single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479152/how-to-deserialize-a-json-array-containing-different-data-types-to-a-single-obje). You probably need a custom JsonConverter that instantiates the appropriate type depending on the `type` string in the JSON.

Comment: Any chance you can share a json sample?

Comment: Could you please show your json to get clear idea about you tried to do so?

Comment: I really wonder though how a boy and girl have so little in common, they don't even share the `parent` stuff, if they would you could make them part link to a `Child` class and let your dictionary take the `Child` as either boy and girl, as it stands, it really is `object` or `dynamic`. So is your question about Json serialization or class design? :)

Comment: Hey @Mask-dCodex, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55536248/4295234 (it is similar to what you need)

Comment: @Mask-dCodex, Did you tried my solution below? because `JsonExtensionData` is for dealing such Json like yours.

Comment: @er-sho Thank you for the solution. Can I ask why you did this?     public ParentObject()
    {
        data = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    }

Comment: @Mask-dCodex, Its just for initialization of  memory for `data` property so you can directly use `.Add` like I did in my answer otherwise you will get `Object reference error` **Or** you can remove this line and then whenever you want to add `boy` or `girl` object then before this you can assign memory to `data` property like `parentObject.data  = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();` so while adding object of boy and girl you will not get `Object reference error`, got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your key/value pair are not fixed and data must be configurable then Newtonsoft.json has one feature that to be use here and that is **`[JsonExtensionData]`** [Read more](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections)

> Extension data is now written when an object is serialized. Reading and writing extension data makes it possible to automatically round-trip all JSON without adding every property to the .NET type you’re deserializing to. Only declare the properties you’re interested in and let extension data do the rest.

In your case, suppose there is a class,

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Qaz { get; set; }
    public string Wsx { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> child { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        child = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    }
}
```

In the above class, you know that `Qaz` and `Wsx` are always present from your json either they contain value or null,

But for dynamic data, you can't say which key/value pair you will receive from your json so the `[JsonExtensionData]` can collect all those key/value pair in a dictionary.

Suppose the below classes will be for your dynamic data,

```
public class ABC
{
    public string Abc { get; set; }
}

public class PQR
{
    public string Pqr { get; set; }
}

public class XYZ
{
    public string Xyz { get; set; }
}
```

**Serialization:**

```
ABC aBC = new ABC { Abc = "abc" };
PQR pQR = new PQR { Pqr = "pqr" };
XYZ xYZ = new XYZ { Xyz = "xyz" };

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.Qaz = "qaz";
myClass.Wsx = "wsx";

myClass.child.Add("ABC", JToken.FromObject(aBC));
myClass.child.Add("PQR", JToken.FromObject(pQR));
myClass.child.Add("XYZ", JToken.FromObject(xYZ));

string outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
```

This will give you json like

```
{
  "Qaz": "qaz",
  "Wsx": "wsx",
  "ABC": {
    "Abc": "abc"
  },
  "PQR": {
    "Pqr": "pqr"
  },
  "XYZ": {
    "Xyz": "xyz"
  }
}
```

**Deserialization:**

```
MyClass myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(outputJson);

string Qaz = myClass.Qaz;
string Wsx = myClass.Wsx;

if (myClass.child.ContainsKey("ABC"))
{
    ABC abcObj = myClass.child["ABC"].ToObject<ABC>();
}

if (myClass.child.ContainsKey("PQR"))
{
    PQR pqrObj = myClass.child["PQR"].ToObject<PQR>();
}

if (myClass.child.ContainsKey("XYZ"))
{
    XYZ pqrObj = myClass.child["XYZ"].ToObject<XYZ>();
}
```

**Conclusion:** The main aim of **`[JsonExtensionData]`** is to keep your json class hierarchy simple and more readable so you don't need to manage class structure for every property.

**Get all dynamic data with the specific key in JToken inside Dictionary :**

You can use LINQ to fetch all dynamic data of particular key from the above dictionary.

```
var allAbcTypes = myClass.child
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value
                      .ToObject<JObject>()
                      .Properties()
                      .Where(p => p.Name == "Abc")    //<= Use "Column" instead of "Abc"
                      .Select(o => new ABC            //<= Use your type that contais "Column" as a property
                      {
                           Abc = o.Value.ToString()
                      })).ToList();
```

In your case, Its something like,

```
var allColumnTypes = myClass.child
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value
                      .ToObject<JObject>()
                      .Properties()
                      .Where(p => p.Name == "Column")
                      .Select(o => new Item
                      {
                         id = x.Value["id "].ToString(),
                         type = x.Value["type "].ToString(),
                         model = x.Value["model"].ToObject<List<string>>(),
                         color = x.Value["color"].ToObject<string[]>()
                      })).ToList();
```

Comment: If I wanted to output lets say all boy objects how can I do that? I can call on the type or id however object name is dynamic

Comment: let me know how much `boy` objects available in your json because on same level json doesn't allow you to add same key with multiple times, please show your sample json to get clear idea that clarify what you want to do?

Comment: I have updated the thread with an example. I am simply trying to generate a list of objects like the structure above but in my chase each object has a unique name but properties are the same. I cant exactly call [Jsonproperty()] as it is always unique

Comment: Your class structure that you updated now is already for unique name for your json showed because you already use Dictionary and this dictionary will handle unique name because dictionary will not permit for duplicate key name except that you have to remove `id` and `type` from `Content` class. And then everything will work for you

Comment: Or I think you want to know that how you populate object that generate the json that you showed in post?

Comment: Ah I see. All properties have been converted to JToken. If I wanted to access all objects with type: "Item" and return the entire object how will I query that? Do I use Linq-JSON? Thanks for your help on this. I didnt see my other objects in the output

Comment: Wait I'll update my answer for deserialization process also so you can get idea about how you can get object from specific JToken

Comment: Lets say. The row contains multiple columns. I want to be able to return the row and its child columns object so I can keep the relationship of both. Also I do not need to add any new objects as I am only extracting data from the input json and reformatting it

Comment: As you said in the above comment *each object has a unique name but properties are the same* so the class `Item` is the same for every unique key but with different data, right?

Comment: The item type will have different properties depending on the type. Whilst row and column will always have the same properties. I would just like to select the row and all columns relating to it. using property parentid in all objects and return json e.g DynamicName-123 will contain 3 columns. return full row, column,column,column so the relationship is saved

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. After attempting this I have a question. This json is obtained via web and I cannot control how many dynamic objects there are. Since it is in a dictionary there exists a key. How can I query lets say all objects with type = "column" and return all column objects from this dictionary. I am not plannnig to add anything on this Json just simply extract the required data

Comment: I added one more section at the last of answer. view it carefully. its working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize to a dictionary with a Key string and a dynamic value (boy or girl in this case), the only way I Know is using Dynamic class:

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> child { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah interesting this might be the solution I need as I dont really care about the Json I am deserializing I simply want to store it and extract data from it. How would I access this data?

Comment: You can use it like other class:
`var dynamic = new Boy(); Console.WriteLine(dynamic.Name)`
But in your case, maybe the best option is cast the object (I not sure what you're going to do with this, but I write you an example): 
`if (element is Boy) { var boy = element as Boy; Your Code in Boy's cases } else if (element is Girl) { var girl = element as Girl; Your code in Girls' cases}`
If other cases where you just want serialize the object the best option is JTOKEN like er-ho saids.